# If dns nameservers resolves host name who resolve nameservers

Tags: dns, nameservers

If i set my domain name server which is www.example.com to ns1.example.com

how ns1.example.com get's it's ip address ?
ns1.example.com has bind installed and configured any everything .. it's a functional dns server .. but how does it resolv to ip of dns server ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register your domain, you need to provide the information of your Name Server
If the Name Server is in the domain you are registering, you will need to provide the IP address for your Name Server.

e.g.
You are registering domain example.com at godaddy.com, you will need to provide the name server

- If you decide to setup your own name server, ns1.example.com, you
  need to provide godaddy the IP address for ns1.example.com
- If you decide to pay ultradns.net to use their name server, you just
  need to give ns1.ultradns.net to godaddy

hope it's clearer

For details, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Authoritative_name_server

> When domain names are registered with a domain name registrar, their
>   installation at the domain registry of a top level domain requires the
>   assignment of a primary name server and at least one secondary name
>   server. The requirement of multiple name servers aims to make the
>   domain still functional even if one name server becomes inaccessible
>   or inoperable.[10] The designation of a primary name server is solely
>   determined by the priority given to the domain name registrar. For
>   this purpose, generally only the fully qualified domain name of the
>   name server is required, unless the servers are contained in the
>   registered domain, in which case the corresponding IP address is
>   needed as well.

Comment: Thank you it is clear now , i knew it was the logical answer but since i don't own a TLD i didn't know how it works at the Registrar side :) thank you again